# Track virtual pageviews in aspnet form with GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to generate virtual pageviews when specific buttons are being clicked on.
I've set up the everything in GTM with the help of this guide:
http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/form-tracking-google-tag-manager/

The Form submit listener and the link click listener are being fired correctly but the "clickedButton" tag won´t fire when a button is being clicked. Therefore, the other tags won´t fire because they are dependent on each other.

Someone who tried the same thing? any tips?

Comment: First, in this guide author is not setting link click listener but click listener. Please, check if you have this set up properly. If you are doing some modifications to things described in the guide, please add those. Second, could you place a screenshot of the Tag and the Rule which is not being fired correctly?

Comment: Hi Tomek. You´re right! I did set it up wrong but it works now. Thanks for the help!